# Facebook Button CSS trick

Tags: css, facebook, button

Does anyone here know how to style a normal button like the famous Facebook button? i have already developed the code, but i need to see whether the experts here do know how to do this or not. Post in your codes if you can do Style a normal button like facebook button.

**UPDATE**

I did not post this question myself. I guess someone else used my profile by some means to do this. Sorry for the disturbance created by this question. I myself want the moderators to delete this. PLEASE.

Comment: Can you explain what is special there ? What do you really want to have ? (screenshots ?)

Comment: @Haza It seems he already has developed some mysterious code...

Comment: Ask a question about the hack over on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make any button look the way you want using an image:

```
.button {
   background-image:url(yourimage.png);
   width:...px;
   height:...px;
   border:none;
}
```